# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 6

Tags: java

```
public class IntegerSet {
int dMax;
boolean[] set;

public IntegerSet(int domainMax) {
    dMax = domainMax + 1;
    set = new boolean[dMax];

}
...some methods...

public static IntegerSet union(IntegerSet s1, IntegerSet s2) {
    IntegerSet union = new IntegerSet(Math.max(s1.dMax, s2.dMax));
    for (int i = 0; i < (Math.max(s1.dMax, s2.dMax)); i++) {

        union.set[i] = (s1.set[i] || s2.set[i]);
    }

    return union;
}
```

Can anyone tell me whats wrong with this?

I can't understand why I'm getting the error message after hours: `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 6`
As the two sets supplied as arguments may have different domain max; the resulting union should have whichever of these two domain max is larger hence why I am using Math.max.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What do you think it means? Once you know that, you can work backwards to figure out the source.

Comment: Imagine, s1.dMax is 10 and s2.dMax is 20. So if you iterate until Max(10,20), which is 20, what will happen with s1.set?

Comment: Insert calls to System.out.println to print out your values, working backwards from the point of the exception.  (Or use a debugger.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem arises when `s1` and `s2` have different lengths. These lines are flawed:

```
IntegerSet union = new IntegerSet(Math.max(s1.dMax, s2.dMax));
for (int i = 0; i < (Math.max(s1.dMax, s2.dMax)); i++) {
```

Think about what two sets of unequal length look like:
(using 1 and 0 in place of `true` and `false`)

```
s1: {0 1 0 0 1 1}               length = 6
s2: {1 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 1}   length = 12
```

You've programmed your loop to iterate from 0 up to the *maximum* length of the two sets, which in the above example is 12 (meaning that the last value your loop will use is 11). But `s1` is only 6 elements long--its last valid index is 5! As the loop erroneously attempts to access elements 7 through 12 (indices 6 through 11) of `s1`, it throws an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.`

To fix this, you should use the *minimum* length of the two sets in both of the lines where you use the maximum. This way, you will be taking the union:

```
s1:    {0 1 0 0 1 1}               length = 6
s2:    {1 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 1}   length = 12
union: {1 1 1 0 1 1}               length = min(6, 12) = 6
```

Instead of

```
s1:    {0 1 0 0 1 1}! ! ! ! ! !    length = 6; no elements 7 through 12!
s2:    {1 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 1}   length = 12
union: {1 1 1 0 1 1 ! ! ! ! ! !}   length = max(6, 12) = 12 -> errors
```

This leaves the later section of `s2` out of the union, as there are no corresponding elements in `s1` to perform a boolean `||` with. However, you could also do something like this:

```
IntegerSet union = new IntegerSet(Math.max(s1.dMax, s2.dMax));

for (int i = 0; i < (Math.max(s1.dMax, s2.dMax)); i++) {

    if (s2.set.length > s1.set.length)
    {
        union.set[i] = s2.set[i] || (i < s1.set.length ? s1.set[i] : false);
    }
    else
    {
        union.set[i] = s1.set[i] || (i < s2.set.length ? s2.set[i] : false);
    }
}
```

This will use `false`'s for every missing element in the shorter set, resulting in the union being:

```
s1:    {0 1 0 0 1 1}               length = 6
s2:    {1 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 1}   length = 12
union: {1 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 1}   length = max(6, 12) = 12
```

All entries are simply copied from the longer set, since `anything || false` is itself.

Comment: Ahh i see! Make sense now! Thanks for making it clear to me! Probably a silly question but wouldn't using min miss out some of elements to create the union? As i would of thought the resulting union should have whichever of these two domain max is larger. I.e. 
's1:{2 4}'
's2:{4 5 6 7 9}'
 
Only gives me {2 4 5 }

Comment: @user3334639 See my edit. I think this may be what you're looking for.

Comment: I can see what your code is doing with your explanation but i didnt think you could apply the || operator to boolean?

Comment: @user3334639 Correct. Sorry, I've been doing a lot of C++ lately. The zero's should be `false`'s instead.

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
dMax = domainMax + 1;
```

should be:

```
dMax = domainMax;
```

Or just use `set.length`.

Answer (score 0):

Your for-loop goes from `0` to the max size of `s1` and `s2`. But because (in the situation that throws errors), one of your `IntegerSet`s is smaller, the for-loop goes past the size of the smaller `IntegerSet` when retrieving all of the `boolean`s from the larger `IntegerSet`

```
for (int i = 0; i < (Math.max(s1.dMax, s2.dMax)); i++) {

    union.set[i] = (s1.set[i] || s2.set[i]);
}
```

If the size of one set is smaller than the max, then you are going to get an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Example:

Say you have the following conditions:

```
s1 = {0, 1, 1, 0, 1}
s2 = {0, 0, 0}
s1.dMax = 5, so s1.set has a size of 5
s2.dMax = 3, so s2.set has a size of 3
```

In your for-loop, you are going to iterate from 0 to 4. When the following occurs:

```
 i = 3
 s1.set[i] = s1.set[3] //IndexOutOfBoundsException because the size of s1.set is 3.
```

You have a couple options of how you can fix this:

- You can add a check in your for-loop to ensure that you aren't
  going to get an `IndexOutOfBoundsException` for your smaller
  `IntegerSet` and just set the index in `union` to the `boolean` value of your larger set.
- You can pad to your smaller `IntegerSet` depending on what you want the
  union to be for the blank indicies.
- Use the `min` size of the two `IntegerSet`s if you want to ignore the
  extra `boolean`s (Judging from the fact that you made the union set
  the size of the max, I am guess that is not the case)

*Side Note:* You also do not need to add the `+1` to the `dMax` variable when you create your `union` `IntegerSet`. That is going to result in your having an extra index that you don't need and could cause problems later.

Comment: But dont i need to have domianMax + 1 to allow for 0? So if i make an array[5] i will end up with {0 1 2 3 4}

Comment: Not sure what you mean. int[] array = new int[5]; initialzies the array with all `0`'s is believe. So it would be {0, 0, 0, 0 ,0}. But you would have 5 inidicies. The value that is being passed into your `IntegerSet` constructor is the size of the other `IntegerSet` so you should not be missing any indicies.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `dMax` as the number of `boolean array` elements in one place, and as the domain maximum (wrong) when you create the new `union` set. (That causes you to make `union` 1 element too large.)

Several things to consider when you rewrite your code:

1. Assuming `domainMax` implies a set of integers from [0, domainMax], do define a boolean array with `domainMax+1` elements (don't bother with a dMax variable, you can get that info by checking `set.length`
2. In the "`union`" function, be sure to handle the case where one or both of the input `IntegerSet`s is null
3. Use `protected set` to make sure the internal representation of the `IntegerSet` is not known or accessed outside your class
4. When you perform the union of two non-null `IntegerSet`s, only perform the or operation (||) for the case where both sets have values; then for the "bigger" set, simply copy over the remaining items.